# Firebase is not correctly exporting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I am working on a project using firebase and the version I have downloaded is 9.8.3 (which iirc is the most current version). However, I am receiving an error message that reads

> ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 16:20-42
> export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/compat/app' (module has no exports)

and while I am certain that I am exporting it incorrectly I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is what my current 'firebase.js' file looks like:

```
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCx0tcar2EmnD2tGQ3CjNDy3-Tf363YiPM",
    authDomain: "starvana2-9d9db.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "starvana2-9d9db",
    storageBucket: "starvana2-9d9db.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "508991125201",
    appId: "1:508991125201:web:8f4b5c7fbf718fb4db77f0",
    measurementId: "G-7S7H73K4HL"
  };
  
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

const db = firebaseApp.fireStore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth,};
export default firebase;
```

Can someone look over it and explain what the issue is? I would be super grateful!

Comment: Are you using Firebase v9?

Comment: Refer this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start